# How to use the OR operator in Views?

Tags: views

How do I create a view that will display all content of type '**Accountancy**' and also all content with a taxonomy term '**Accountancy**' (of any content type)?

I am trying this with a filter of `Type: Accountancy` OR `Taxonomy: Accountancy` but this is only showing the taxonomy nodes. The only filter that would work was the Delta.

[image]

Thanks Елин Й & morbiD - You both suggest the same answer, however, this does not work, please see screen shot below. (N.B. all this content is not published and only used these views)
[image]

Comment: For some reason, the fact that your nodes are unpublished seems to affect the results when using a "Content: Taxonomy terms on node" relationship. However, it still works properly for me if I use the "Content: <field name>" relationship instead. Also, make sure your relationship is **not** set to be required.

Answer (score 3):

- Add a *Relationship* **Content: Taxonomy terms on node** under **Advanced** section:
  [image: Screenshot relationship]
- Select the vocabulary:
  [image: Relationship vocabulary selection]
- Add the filter **Taxonomy term: Name**.
  [image]
- Enter **Value**  *Accountancy*. 
  [image]
- Click "And/Or, Rearrange" for the **Filter Criteria** and make it read like:

> **Content: Published Yes** AND (**Content: Type = Accountancy** OR **(term) Taxonomy term: Name = Accountancy**)

[image] 
[image]

Comment: This won't work the way the question wants. The "Content: Has taxonomy term" filter adds an inner join to the query which means content without the taxonomy term won't show up even if it's of the right content type.

Comment: @morbiD Thanks, you're right. I've updated the answer using another filter "Taxonomy term: Name"

Comment: Thank you Елин Й. & @morbiD, but this does not work, please see screenshot above.

Comment: @IamOnStage According to your latest update on your question, that the nodes are indeed unpublished, the answer of morbiD is more accurate. I won't update my answer to avoid unnecessary duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Please add another filter there of taxonomy field as **OR** condition and for can **Empty** condition. It will load all the content content of type '**Accountancy**' which not have the taxonomy term assigned.

Remember this will be a new filter with OR condition.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following relationship:

- Content: <your taxonomy field name>

Then add your filters:

- Content: Type (= Accountancy) **OR**
- Taxonomy term: Term (= Accountancy)

where the taxonomy term filter uses the relationship you added.

Note: Views seems a bit flaky about letting you choose the taxonomy term you want to filter so you might have to save your view after you add the filter and then edit it again in order select a term.

Update: Given that your nodes are unpublished, this only seems to work properly by using a "Content: <taxonomy field name>" relationship. For example, if my non-accountancy content types have a taxonomy field called "Tags" then the following works:

[image: View settings]